# breaking out of _.filter()

Tags: underscore.js

```
_.filter(this.pluck(key),function(item){
    return item ? value.toLowerCase() === item.toLowerCase() : false;
  });
```

Is there a way to stop the filter iteration if the return value of the callback is true?

Comment: Unclear: what's the context of this code? Will the filtered data be used or should only be tested whether certain values exist? What's the reason of using `filter()` and wanting to break on some condition? -- Yes this Q is "old" but user still may stumble upon it.

Answer (score 2):

I found out this can be done with [`any`](http://underscorejs.org/#some) (aka `some`):

```
_.any(this.pluck(key),function(item){
        return item ? value.toLowerCase() === item.toLowerCase() : false;
      });
```

Comment: `any()` is no "breakable" replacement for [`filter()`](http://underscorejs.org/#filter) since the ladder will return an array of values matched while the first returns true/false. If your initial intent was to check _if_ a collection contains certains values `any()` would be fine, otherwise, if you want to use the filtered data too `any()` is not the right thing. I'd use a `for`/`while` loop and `break;` accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Such worse - but the best approach seems to be to handle your DS like (or convert to) an array and iterate with a `for`-loop or equivalent with a `break;` conditon.

Please Downvote *AND* awnser the quest. if this is wrong. ;)